# How can you pre-sign requests to AWS with credentials using the AWS Java SDK?

Tags: java, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0, aws-credentials, aws-sdk-java

I have a situation where I need to take a Java application that currently uses Basic auth to access OpenSearch, and add the ability for a user to provide a Cognito user-pool user/pass instead of the Basic user/pass.

It appears that the way to do this transparently (i.e. with raw requests, rather than using the OpenSearch Java client/library) is by taking the arbitrary requests and pre-signing them, in cases when Basic auth is not used.

I've figured out how to negotiate the Cognito user-pool user/pass into `Credentials` using the AWS Java SDK, and confirmed that I can sign `curl` requests with the `--aws-sigv4` option, but I'm at a loss as to how to incorporate signing (with [`Aws4Signer.presign()`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/auth/signer/internal/BaseAws4Signer.html#presign(software.amazon.awssdk.http.SdkHttpFullRequest,software.amazon.awssdk.auth.signer.params.Aws4PresignerParams)) ?)

Essentially what I'm trying for is a Java SDK 2.0 equivalent to a curl call like

```bash
curl \
--aws-sigv4 "aws:amz:us-west-2:es" \
--user "$ACCESS_KEY_ID":"$SECRET_KEY" \
--header "x-amz-security-token: ${SESSION_TOKEN}"  \
https://some-opensearch-host.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com/_search
```

where the variable values are provided by the `Credentials` object.

I might just be bad at reading Java docs (or the AWS SDK docs) because, taking `Aws4Signer.presign()` as an example, I have no idea where/how to get the information about `ExecutionAttributes` that would allow me to use them (and thus, `presign()`) correctly.